# Express JS: How to let query wait for the return result of Mongonese virtual property

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I try to query on other Schema in virtual property without reference ID, and found the returned result did not include that virtual property. Function populate() cannot be used since 2 schemas are not linked right? What method can let the query wait till result is ready before return?

member.js

```
var MemberSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {type: String, maxlength: 100},
    joinYear: {type: Number, min: 1980}
  }
);


// Virtual that can be found in query result
PatientSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(function () {
  return '/member/' + this._id;
});


// Virtual that cannot be found in query result, but console.log display correct value
// it try to count documents of Event Schema, that happened same year as member join.
MemberSchema
.virtual('eventInJoinYearCount')
.get(function () {
    Event.countDocuments({eventYear:this.joinYear})
.then((myCount) =>{console.log(myCount); return myCount}); 


//query result included virtual properties
MemberSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });


//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Member', MemberSchema);
```

member.find function applied in memberController.js

```
exports.search = function(req, res,next) {   
    async.parallel({
         memberList: function(callback) {
             Member.find({"name": {$regex: ".*"+req.query.FindString, $options:"i"}}).exec(callback);
        },      

    }, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        res.render('index', { error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discover that populate function is still powerful enough to handle this case.

Here's the virtual property I revised

```
//get 
MemberSchema
.virtual('eventInJoinYearCount',{
  ref: 'Event', // The model to use
  localField: 'joinYear', // Find people where `localField`
  foreignField: 'eventYear', // is equal to `foreignField`
  count: true // And only get the number of docs
});
```

And the modified controller

```
exports.search = function(req, res,next) {   
    async.parallel({
         memberList: function(callback) {
             Member.find({"name": {$regex: ".*"+req.query.FindString, $options:"i"}}).populate('eventInJoinYearCount').exec(callback);
        },      

    }, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        res.render('index', { error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```